# Does std::vector::pop_back set the pointers of the objects in it to nullptr?

Tags: c++, stdvector, nullptr

Does `std::vector::pop_back` set the pointers of the objects in it to `nullptr` or does it just delete the objects?

I see that the size of my vector decreases so the object is obviously deleted but I want to know whether the pointers are set to `nullptr` or do I have to do that manually?

Edit: I asked this question in according to a vector containing pointers. Example: `vector<Bitmap*>`.

Comment: More then likely nothing happens except the size member is decremented by 1.  the size of the vector and the capacity of the vector are 2 different things.

Comment: What pointers are you talking about? Sounds like Java...

Comment: What pointers are you talking about? If your vector contains pointers, then nothing is done to them when they're removed. If it contains objects involving pointers, then it depends what their destructor does.

Comment: Why do you care? A conforming program won't be able to tell the difference (you are not planning to access an element with an index out of bounds, are you)? What do you mean you "*have to* do that manually"? Who's forcing you?

Comment: What exactly is the question about? The object popped from the vector is immediately destroyed. It ceases to exist. What difference does it make whether some "pointers" inside that object were set to null or not? You will never know that anyway since the object no longer exists.

Comment: Well to clear this out for you guys, at the school where I am a student, we have to set every pointer that we have made for an instance of a class to nullptr after we have deleted it, so that's why I'm asking this question. I hope this cleared some things up for you.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I am talking about a vector that contains pointers, and thank you, by saying nothing happens to them you just gave me the answer! I guess setting them to nullptr has to be done manually then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logically, the 'destructor' of the object popped is called. Note however that for an integral type (and a pointer is an integral type), the 'destructor' is a no-op.

What this means is:

Here `Thing::~Thing()` will be called:

```
std::vector<Thing> things;
things.emplace_back({});
things.pop_back();
```

Here nothing will be called and you will have a resource leak

```
std::vector<Thing*> things;
things.emplace_back(new Thing{});
things.pop_back();
```

Here `std::unique_ptr<Thing>::~std::unique_ptr<Thing>()` will be called and you will not have a resource leak

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Thing>> things;
things.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Thing>());
things.pop_back();
```

Answer (score 4):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/pop_back/

The end iterator and any iterator, pointer and reference referring to the removed element are invalidated.
Iterators, pointers and references referring to other elements that have not been removed are guaranteed to keep referring to the same elements they were referring to before the call.

If your vector contains directly objects, the destructor of the object is called.
Obviously if you are using a vector of pointer (with ownership) you MUST call delete yourself.

```
std::vector<P*> myvector;
...
delete myvector.back();
myvector.pop_back();
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back

```
void pop_back();
```

Removes the last element of the container.
Calling `pop_back` on an empty container is undefined.
No iterators or references except for `back()` and `end()` are invalidated.

I wouldn't assume or extrapolate anything beyond that.

Comment: Well after I searched for it, I ended up on that too and that's why I was wondering if it did set it to nullptr or not. That's why I asked, I couldn't find it anywhere else. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: @JulianDeclercq You haven't explained *what* exactly would get set to `nullptr`. Maybe some example code would help to clarify your question.

Comment: I got it fixed now :D Thanks to everyone here